# Logstash read a very large number of static xml files ( input file plugin)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have many xml static file about 1 million in one directory. I want to read and parse those file with logstash and output to elasticsearch.
 I have the next input config (I try many way and it`s my last version):

```
input{
 file {
               path => "/opt/lun/data-unzip/ftp/223/*.xml*"
               exclude => "*.zip"
               type => "223-purplan"
               start_position => beginning
               discover_interval => "3"
               max_open_files => "128"
                close_older => "3"
                codec => multiline {
                        pattern => "xml version"
                        negate => true
                        what => "previous"
                        max_lines => "9999"
                        max_bytes => "100 MiB"
                }
       }
}
```

My server use CentOS 6.8 and the next hardware:
80G memory
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5620  @ 2.40GHz
with 16 cpu`s

Logstash(5.1.2) and elasticsearch(5.1.2) installing in this server.

This config work very slow - about 4 file per second

How can I do it so more fast parsing?

Answer (score 0):

There're few ways that could increase the processing of `logstash`, but then it's really to hard to point out which one should be done. Maybe you could try increasing the sizes of `*pipeline.workers, pipeline.batch.size, and pipeline.batch.delay*` in order to tune the [pipeline performance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logstash-settings-file.html#logstash-settings-file).

**AND** there are few [troubleshooting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/performance-troubleshooting.html#performance-troubleshooting) ways in order to quickly diagnose and resolve Logstash performance issues. You could also try **optimizing** your inputs by removing all filters, and again send all the documents to ***/dev/null*** to ensure that there is no bottleneck with processing or outputting your documents.

Try adding this line to your `file`:

```
sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
```

You might also want to have a look at the [Tuning and Profiling Logstash Performance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/tuning-logstash.html#tuning-logstash) & [this](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-configuration-tuning) blog post. Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried to remove xpath xml parsing, and i have good result - over 100 xml rep sec.
Parsing is a bottleneck. How can I optimize xpath parsing or increase the amount of resources allocated to parse? I tried tune *pipeline.workers, pipeline.batch.size, and pipeline.batch.delay* but but I did not get the result of more than 10 xmk per sec. I think is very bad result for my server.